# AWS CloudFoundation Template error: Invalid template resource property 'VpcId' YAML format

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

**Problem**

Using AWS CloudFormation YAML to create resource stack with EC2, etc and RDS database. Have specific issue with reference use of VPC on parameters for resources.

**Template format error**

Resource   VPC:Type: AWS::EC2::VPC in YAML script is defined at top.

CloudFormation stack error: Invalid template resource property 'VpcId'

Scope of where error resides is in reference to property VpcID. For example, I use AttachGateway with VpcId: !Ref VPC. As I am new to CloudFormation stack template, what is the stack error specifically addressing that I coded it wrong on reference to VpcId: !Ref VPC

```
   Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

   Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

   Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

   Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

   Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

**CloudFormation Template with Error**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:

  DBInstance:
    Default: DBInstance
    Description: My database instance
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '63'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'

  DBName:
    Default: mydb
    Description: My database
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '64'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'

  DBInstanceClass:
    Default: db.m5.large
    Description: DB instance class
    Type: String

  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Default: '50'
    Description: The size of the database (GiB)
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '20'
    MaxValue: '65536'

  DBUsername:
    Type: String
    Description: Master username for the RDS instance
    Default: admin

  DBPassword:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
    Description: Master password for the RDS instance
    Default: password

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: VPC

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: VPC Internet Gateway

  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public Subnet 1

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private Subnet 1

  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.3.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public Subnet 2

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.4.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private Subnet 2

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public Route Table

  PublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  PrivateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Private Route Table

  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable

  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable

  #EC2 Instances
  EC2Instance1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref EC2SecurityGroup
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      KeyName: EC2Instance1
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          yum update -y
          yum install -y httpd
          systemctl start httpd
          systemctl enable httpd
          #echo "<h1>Hello from Region us-east-2b</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html

  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'

  # EC2 and ALB Security Groups
  ELBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: ELB Security Group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/24

  SSHSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Limits security group egress traffic
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 127.0.0.1/32
          IpProtocol: "-1"
    VpcId: !Ref VPC

  EC2SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: EC2 Security Group
      DependsOn: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        SourceSecurityGroupId:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - ELBSecurityGroup
          - GroupId
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'myBucketV5'

  S3BucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref EC2SecurityGroup
      KeyName: S3BucketPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 's3:*'
            Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/*'
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/@matthew'

  EC2TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 15
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: '200'
      Name: EC2TargetGroup
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetGroupAttributes:
      - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
        Value: '20'
      Targets:
      - Id: !Ref EC2Instance1
        Port: 80
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3

  ALBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref EC2TargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ApplicationLoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP

  ApplicationLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets:
      - !Ref PublicSubnet1
      - !Ref PublicSubnet2
      SecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt ELBSecurityGroup.GroupId

  MyRDS:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstance
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBInstanceClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref EC2SecurityGroup
      KeyName: MyRDS

Outputs:
  EC2InstanceId:
    Description: InstanceId of EC2 instance
    Value: !Ref EC2Instance1

  S3BucketName:
    Description: S3 bucket
    Value: !Ref S3Bucket

  DBInstanceId:
    Description: DBInstanceIdentifier of RDS instance
    Value: !Ref DBInstance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation of `VpcId`  in `SSHSecurityGroup` is incorrect. It should be:

```
  SSHSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Limits security group egress traffic
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 127.0.0.1/32
          IpProtocol: "-1"
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```